# Paginate system display all result

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I want to create paginate system. I have this code:

```
(function (name) {
    var container = $('#pagination-' + name);
    container.pagination({
        dataSource: '/ajax/allads',
        locator: 'items',
        totalNumber: 3,
        pageSize: 2,
        ajax: {
            beforeSend: function () {
                container.prev().html('Loading...');
            }
        },
        callback: function (response, pagination) {

            window.console && console.log(22, response, pagination);
            var dataHtml = '<ul>';

            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                dataHtml += '<li>' + item.title+ '</li>';
            });

            dataHtml += '</ul>';

            container.prev().html(dataHtml);
        }
    })
})('demo2');
```

It display 2 page but everytime it displayall result. Why?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us which plugin you're using for the pagination?

Comment: This library is pagination.js

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your backend system. The result is basically from your response. Or you have to make your question more clear.

Comment: I thought about it. I can code backend system to normal paginate but how can I integrate this with paginate.js library? Address with example look like this `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?`. I can send the number of page in address like this 'localhost:8000/ajax/ads/1' but it does't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors are you getting etc?

Comment: It display everything